# ComboBox generate ICallbackEventHandler not found

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, asp.net-ajax

Im using Devexpress ASP.NET AJAX ComboBox and trying to filter the result using callback events. This is the ASP markup for the ComboBox control

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server"
    EnableViewState="false"
    Width="100%" ID="Project"
    ValueField="Value" TextField="Text"
    CallbackPageSize="10"
    EnableCallbackMode="true"
    IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains"
    OnItemsRequestedByFilterCondition="Project_ItemsRequestedByFilterCondition"
    OnCallback="Project_Callback"
    DropDownRows="10"
    TextFormatString="{0} {1}">
    <Columns>
        <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="Projekt" FieldName="Value" Name="value" />
        <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="Kund" FieldName="Text" Name="text" />
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

And here is the code behind

```
protected void Project_ItemsRequestedByFilterCondition(object source, DevExpress.Web.ListEditItemsRequestedByFilterConditionEventArgs e)
{
    var data = handler.GetProjectList(e.Filter);
    Project.DataSource = data;
    Project.DataBind();
}

protected void Project_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
{

}
```

Every time i try to write in the combobox the page says that the IEventCallBackHandler is not found. Please see the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The page is inherit our own base class that has a custom implementation of FindControl.